# Can I get iOS App Installs into Mixpanel?

Tags: app-store-connect, mixpanel, itunesconnect-analytics

Is there any way to get the number of Apple iOS Installs (from iTunes Connect) into my Mixpanel for tracking? Has anyone figured this out? Looking to track Acquisition figures for my App.

If the answer is No, is there an Analytics platform that does integrate with iTunes for this data?

Answer (score 0):

Try out appfigures, it gives you install numbers from the app store and some other helpful information. Unfortunately though, you can't track app installs to mixpanel directly.